# How to programmatically show a controller that has a navigation controller and tabbar controller as defined in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I'd like to show the tableview controller embedded in the navigation controller from the app delegate.

The reason I need to do this is I'm building a wrapper over an api, so to login I direct users to a relevant webpage where they can login to grant my app access to their credentials, then they are sent to a relevant url end point which triggers my app. At this point I want to load the tableviewcontroller in the navigation and tabbarcontroller.

Is it possible to define multiple entry points on storyboards?

A screenshot of my current storyboard configuration is shown here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wfo5werrs6vwy1/Screenshot%202014-10-09%2008.43.15.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define multiple entry points on storyboards. To achieve this, you should use `[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]` and set the view controller to root view controller in your app delegate based on your condition.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSString *identifier
    if (/* path A */){
        identifier = @"vc1";
    } else {
        identifier = @"vc2";
    }
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: I'm also using a UITabBarController and UINavigationController as seen in the link here https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wfo5werrs6vwy1/Screenshot%202014-10-09%2008.43.15.png?dl=0 . Since the navigationcontroller is technically the root of both the tabbarcontroller and the tableviewcontroller I would just instantiate the navigationcontroller?

Comment: Sure you can. Is there any problem?